# Two different Payment Gateway for one payment

Tags: php, api, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I'm building functionality in which product payment is divided into two parts - 
1. service charge
2. actual payment

service charge payment will be done thr' stripe api (as client wants this gateway)
actual payment will be done thr' any type of gateway as per user selection.

But, crucial part is, both parts of payment should be done on one click.
On one click, it should go to stripe and other gateway that user has selected.

Can it be possible?

If yes, what will happen in the case where one of the two parts of payments is successful and other one failes.

Where can I redirect success url for both types of payments? on same page or another page?

As card details will be given only once by user in one form and submitted, can these details remain secure while processing of two transactions?

I have thoroughly searched for this, but can't find answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a credit card payment only (and not a wallet such as PayPal or WebMoney, etc) all you need to do is store the credit-card details at your servers. Just make sure you are PCI compliant for that.
In this case, you will charge the service fee via stripe and the actual payment via the 2nd payment gateway. Just make sure you refund one if the other failed. Also ensure that the user is well aware that he will see TWO charges on his card. I would advise showing that nicely in the invoice page.
So it's not that complex of a flow for stored credit cards, but if you lack the credit card data and let the user pick an online payment option such as PayPal, then you'll need to ensure this online payment is successfully completed before charging the service fee via stripe.